# cocos2dx - Custom Fragment Shader and CCRenderTexture

Tags: cocos2d-x, fragment-shader

I have a `CCRenderTexture` that is filled with a sprite when the scene is loaded, as follows,

```
canvas = CCRenderTexture::create(this->getContentSize().width, this->getContentSize().height);
canvas->setPosition(data->position);
canvas->beginWithClear(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0);
this->visit();
canvas->end();
```

The above code is written within a class, which derives from CCSprite (Hence `this`).

Then, in another function `applyShader()`, I create a sprite named `splat`, from the texture of `CCRenderTexture *canvas`. Thus `splat` will contain the whole texture of `canvas`.

Now I apply a custom fragment shader to the `splat` by calling the function `splat->renderShader()`, which will modify some small portion of the whole  texture.

Then I draw the modified texture back to the `CCRenderTexture *canvas`.

Hence, `applyShader()` will
 * take a texture from CCRenderTexture,
 * create a sprite based on it,
 * apply a fragment shader to it
 * and draw the modified texture back to CCRenderTexture.

This `applyShader()` will be called repetitively and its code is as follows:

```
splat = Splat::createWithTexture(art->canvas->getSprite()->getTexture());
splat->renderShader();
art->canvas->begin();
splat->visit();
art->canvas->end();
```

My shader code is (nothing fancy)

```
precision mediump float;

varying vec2 v_texCoord;
uniform sampler2D u_texture;
uniform sampler2D u_colorRampTexture;
uniform float params[5];

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord);
    return;
}
```

So, with the above code I expect the original sprite `this` to get rendered over and over again without any visual changes. But on each call to `applyShader()`, the texture is getting stretched a little and the stretched image is getting rendered. After some 10 calls, the image gets so distorted.

Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong?

Thanks :-)

PS: All code shown here is partial, not complete code.

Edit: Adding Screens
[image: Render Texture Problem]

Update:
**The problem has nothing to do with shaders it seems. It happens even when I dont call `renderShader()`.** The actual lines of code is:

```
splat = Splat::createWithTexture(art->canvas->getSprite()->getTexture());
splat->setPosition( ccp( art->getContentSize().width * 0.5, art->getContentSize().height * 0.5 ) );
splat->setFlipY(true);
art->canvas->begin();
splat->visit();
art->canvas->end();
```

Comment: Can you include video or images of what's happening? It may help to spot the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution, but something that improves the situation

```
splat->setScale(0.995f);
```

Since the problem appears to be the `Splat` which gets scaled up a bit for some reason, I am trying to scale (down) it back. But 0.995f doesnt give exact results, I am in search for a `magic` number between 0.994 and 0.995 !!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you already solved this or not, but try this:

```
art->canvas->beginWithClear();
splat->visit();
art->canvas->end();
```

Comment: Could you add anything about why someone should do this? Ideally, readers should be able to understand what's significant about his, and when they might like to use it.